# Pandas - Issue when concatenating multiple csv files into one

Tags: pandas, csv, concatenation

I have a list of csv files that I am trying to concatenate using Pandas.

Given below is sample view of the csv file:

Note: Column 4 - stores the latitude
      Column 5 - store the longitude

```
store-001,store_name,building_no_060,23.4324,43.3532,2018-10-01 10:00:00,city_1,state_1
store-002,store_name,building_no_532,12.4345,45.6743,2018-10-01 12:00:00,city_2,state_1
store-003,store_name,building_no_536,54.3453,23.3444,2018-07-01 04:00:00,city_3,state_1
store-004,store_name,building_no_004,22.4643,56.3322,2018-04-01 07:00:00,city_2,state_3
store-005,store_name,building_no_453,76.3434,55.4345,2018-10-02 16:00:00,city_4,state_2
store-006,store_name,building_no_456,35.3455,54.3334,2018-10-05 10:00:00,city_6,state_2
```

When I try to concat multiple csv files in the above format, I see the columns having latitude and longitude are first saved in the first row from A2 - A30 and they are followed by the other columns all in the row 1.

Given below is the way I am performing the concat:

```
masterlist = glob.glob('path') <<- This is the path where all the csv files are stored.

df_v1 = [pd.read_csv(fp, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False).assign(FileName=os.path.basename(fp)) for fp in masterlist] <<-- This also includes the file name in the csv file
df = pd.concat(df_v1, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('path'), index=False)  <<-- This stores the final concatenated csv file
```

Could anyone guide me why is the concatenation not working properly. Thanks

Comment: It seems data related problem, is possible find problematic files?  Maybe different columns names, maybe different separator, hard to know...

Comment: @jezrael, I have manually checked each of the files and found they are of the same structure and load up fine when opened individually. Wondering if there is another way to concat multiple csv files other then how I have tried doing.

Comment: So it is problem with all files?

Comment: I mean when I open the csv in a spreadsheet it loads properly. Only when I try to do the concat function this problem arises. I have also tried to do a concat using 'cat' function in mac and it merged properly.. Only when I am trying using pandas does this error occur..

Comment: @jezrael, so I do not think the problem is with the file..

Comment: Hmmm, one idea - is there same columns names, same csv headers?

Comment: Yes the table structure is exactly the same in all the files

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: Yes it is, hence the mocked up data in the sample.. But the format is exactly as the source is..

Comment: Sorry, I am really confused - if same structure, same separators, same headers in each file then `concat` working nice. If not, there has to be some problem in data :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183109/discussion-between-kevin-nash-and-jezrael).